# Xcode/firebase, search bar "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, searchbar

I have now tried for hours to find the problem, but im new to xcode so..

I made a search bar for which I wanted to add user profiles.
(The search bar worked fine before I changed it)
So that you would be able to search for a user, click and enter a new view controller with the details.
But when I run it, the simulator crashes and the search bar doesnt work.

In viewDidLoad I added:

```
databaseRef.child("Buyers").queryOrdered(byChild: "Personnr").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
    self.usersArray.append(snapshot.value as? NSDictionary)

        let key = snapshot.key
        let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        snapshot?.setValue(key, forKey: "Personnr")
```

"Personnr" is the user. (which is different for all users)

This should take them to the new viewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: (Any)?) {

    let visKunderProfileViewController = segue.destination as!
    ProfileViewController

    visKunderProfileViewController.loggedInUser = self.loggedInUser


    if let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let user = usersArray[indexpath.row]
        visKunderProfileViewController.otherUser = user
    }

}
```

In the new viewController I added:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.databaseRef = Database.database().reference()

    databaseRef.child("Buyers").child((self.loggedInUser!.uid)).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.loggedInUserData = snapshot.value as?
            NSDictionary

        self.loggedInUserData?.setValue(self.loggedInUser!.uid, forKey: "Personnr")

    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }

    databaseRef.child("Buyers").child(self.otherUser?["Personnr"] as! String).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        let uid = self.otherUser?["Personnr"] as! String
        self.otherUser = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.otherUser?.setValue(uid, forKey: "Personnr")

    }) { (error) in
        print(error)
    }

    self.Navn.text = self.otherUser?["Fornavn"] as? String
```

The message I get is: "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"

I checked all the buttons and outlets, everything is connected and no other errors are shown.

Please ask if there is anything else you need to know.
Thanks

Comment: Please put some more details of the crash from the logs. You might want to add an `exception breakpoint` by going to the left navigator of the Xcode and click on the `breakpoint navigator` (2nd to the last tab). Then click on the `+` sign at the bottom and add an `exception breakpoint`.